# Correct spelling of web browser?

Tags: terminology, software

What is the correct spelling of "web browser" (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, etc.) in the context of a software user interface, either as single word (e.g. as a menu item caption) or inside a phrase (e.g. "Output the data in your web browser")?

- WebBrowser
- Web Browser
- Web-Browser
- webbrowser
- web-browser
- web browser

Comment: *Web browser* is a relatively new term. You, as well as anybody, have the divinely appointed opportunity to contribute to and decide the "correct spelling". Don't let the corporations restrict you.

Comment: You forgot *web rouser, wee browser,* and *we browse here*.

Comment: Why would a menu item caption have to be one word? _Web browser_ is two words, not one. A hyphenated spelling _web-browser_ is unusual, but would probably not be noticed as actually incorrect by many; a joint spelling _webbrowser_, on the other hand, is vanishingly rare and would probably be considered wrong by nearly everyone.

Comment: @tchrist And of course _we browse her_. (The Internet is female, right?)

Comment: I also tend to see "web browser" as the most acceptable spelling. How would you spell it as a menu item caption? "Web browser" or "Web Browser"?

Comment: Isn't someone going to suggest a novel use for the diaeresis?

Comment: @BlessedGeek Thank you. You gave me back that divine feeling... ;-)

Comment: This is not a dating site, Peter.

Comment: This is a true statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "a **Web browser**." I am of the old school that likes to capitalize "Web," and I don't remember seeing "browser" capitalized too many times.

Peruse [some of the books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20web%20browser%20in%20this%20application%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22a%20web%20browser%20is%22)  available at Google Books, and you'll find it in heavy use.

In the end, the decision is going to lie with your publisher's editors :-), but be prepared to argue your choice.